# SV lrm interpretation for v2k libraries

Tags: system-verilog

this is a question for lrm experts. I am trying to find an lrm saying about parsing of v2k lib contents and finding some bits and pieces which contradicts each other. So, here is a schematic example:

```
library lib1 pkg1.sv, top1.sv, mod1.sv;
library lib2 pkg2.sv, top2.sv, mod2.sv;

pkg1.sv and pkg2.sv
    package pkg;
       ...
    endpackage

top1.sv and top2.sv:
    module top()
       import pkg::*;
       mod mod(...);
       ...
    endmodule

mod1.sv and mod2.sv
     module mod(...);
        ...
     endmodule

sometop.sv
module sometop();
   mod mod1(...);
   mod mod2(...);
   ...
endmodule
config v1;
   ...
   mod1 use lib1.mod;
   mod2 use lib2.mod;
endconfig
```

In the example above same module names and same package names are in multiple libraries.  It has been proven that vcs parses the all packages and hierarchies from lib1 for mod1 and from lib2 if for mod2. This is an expected behavior from the consumer point of view.

However,

> **33.4** A configuration may change the binding of a module, primitive, interface, or program instance, but shall not change the binding of a package.
>
> **33.2.1** A library is a named collection of cells. A cell is a design element (see 3.2), such as a module, primitive,interface, program, **package**, or configuration.

The standards talks a lot of binding cells to the libraries, but I could not find any clause that would dictate that the compiler has to chose hierarchies or packages from the same library.

Can someone explain this behavior from LRM point of view?

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction here. Packages must be compiled before they can be imported and they are bound at that time (IEEE 1800-2017 26.3). When you compile `lib1` you are binding `lib1.pkg` with `lib2.mod` and `lib2.pkg` with `lib1.mod`.

The `config` clause is changing the binding of `sometop` with `lib1.mod` or `lib2.mod`. The packages that these modules were bound to remain unchanged.

Comment: to me this sounds like a very loose interpretation of the standard.  For example, i can have command line as the following: pkg1.sv, pkg2.sv, top1.sv, top2.sv, ... Will it bind correct packages to the correct modules as specified in the library list?

Comment: I still see no contradiction in the LRM. But I now see some confusion with your example. The `import` statement in the top1.sv and top2.sv files have no bearing on which package gets associated with the module mod.  Imports apply to a lexical scope and have no effect on elaboration, and in this case, could not possibly be influenced by a `config` construct.

Comment: Also, the LRM leaves a lot open to how tools implement the standard when compiling SystemVerilog code. But whenever you compile your code and there is an `import` statement, tools must decide which pre-compiled package that binds to and cannot change the decision at a later time.

Comment: right, and there is nothing in the standard which requires binding to the package from the same library as the importer. Neither it says anything about binding to the modules for instances. Some folks are trying to build a methodology around behavior of a particular tool and i am uneasy with this because the standard is too opened for interpretation.